# Swagger CodeGen swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.25.jar| issue:Can't load config class with name jaxrs-jersey

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate Swagger Stubs from within the java code through swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.25.jar using ProcessBuilder. Input is OAS 3.0.0 valid YAML.

I have the following code :

```
String javaBin = javaHome + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
command.add(javaBin);
command.add("-jar");
command.add(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//lib//swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.25.jar");
command.add("generate");
command.add("-l jaxrs-jersey");
command.add("-i " + oasYAML.getAbsolutePath());
command.add("-o D:\\EmailStatement\\swaggercode");
```

Same CLI command works fine from CMD, but getting below error from within java code :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load config class with name jaxrs-jersey Available: dart
aspnetcore
csharp
csharp-dotnet2
go
go-server
dynamic-html
html
html2
java
jaxrs-cxf-client
jaxrs-cxf
inflector
jaxrs-cxf-cdi
jaxrs-spec
jaxrs-jersey
jaxrs-di
jaxrs-resteasy-eap
jaxrs-resteasy
micronaut
spring
nodejs-server
openapi
openapi-yaml
kotlin-client
kotlin-server
php
python
python-flask
r
ruby
scala
scala-akka-http-server
swift3
swift4
swift5
typescript-angular
typescript-axios
typescript-fetch
javascript

at io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:31)
at io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jaxrs-jersey
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:29)
```

Comment: From within Java code, you might have to specify the fully qualified class name for jersey configuration like this `-l io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig`. Furthermore, if you get `ClassNotFoundException` for this config class, please double your dependency list to see if you have this  `<groupId>io.swagger</groupId><artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>`

Comment: @ssasi hi, thanks for the reply, i tried using fully qualified name  like this -l io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig and also added "swagger-jersey2-jaxrs" jar dependency. But this is not working for me, I am still getting ClassNotFound exception: Can't load config class with name  io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig......Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error. For hours I ve debugged the problem. Finally figured out that key value pair string should not contain space between param key and the value, for example in your code remove the space between `-l` and j`axrs-jersey`. Should be something like this : `command.add("-ljaxrs-jersey");`. Remove all similar occurences of spaces. The library should trim the value before using it.